# iPhone Bluetooth Pairing: Order of Precedence

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

If I have several bluetooth headsets paired to my iPhone and only one headset can be used at a time, how does the phone decide which one to use? For example, here is the ordered list of devices currently paired to my iPhone:
BlueBuds
Car Audio
Logitech Headset
Jabra Wave

If all 4 are turned on and in range, how does my iPhone decide which one to use? Is there any way to change the order without repairing the devices? Does the first device paired stay at the top of the list and have highest precedence, or is it the other way around?

Comment: Is that a programming question? If not, there are no place for it in SO.
For your question, try to switch on device one after the others, once the previous one did connect. Look which one renders sounds.

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer my question:
It looks like the order they are listed on my settings screen doesn't matter. Nor does the order they are paired. What determines precedence is the order they are connected for that session. The last connected device has the highest precedence and is the one used.

For example, if all devices are off it uses the phone speakers. When I turn on the Logitech Headset, music and calls are routed through that device. If I then turn on the BlueBuds, the Logitech goes silent and now the Buds take over. If I move to my car, the music gets redirected to the car audio. The order of precedence rolls back in reverse as I shut down the audio devices.

Comment: Why dose the BlueBud take precedence of the Logitech Headset?  The Logitech Headset is the last connected device if it is the one you're listening to before turning on the BlueBuds.  It's disheartening to know that it is now 2023, a decade later, and Apple still hasn't responded to what is now a much-complained-about problem and has not provided a prioritization on the list of paired devices.